# Force print statement to a single line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, string-formatting

I’m familiar with text wrapping, however I was wondering if there was a way to prevent text from wrapping. If you have a long print statement, when it reaches the end of the line it automatically wraps around and starts a new line. Is there a way I can force it to print the entire statement to one line even if it doesn’t all fit? I would rather the text cut off when it reaches the end of the window rather than it wrapping to the next line.

More precisely: I’m trying to list the contents of a directory on one line, and only one line, because the next line will list the contents of a different directory. It’s only meant to give a preview of what a directory contains so I don’t care if the program doesn’t output all the contents if they can’t all fit on one line. However, I want it to take advantage of as much horizontal space as it’s given. Rather than making the code factor in the width of the window(even if the user resizes it) and the length of each filename to determine how many filenames it can fit in a single line. I was curious if it would just be easier and more efficient to just cut the text off at the end of the line, especially since none of the directories are going to have more than 15 files and are often less (but sometimes the contents can’t all fit on one line). Here's a rough example of what I'm trying:

```
import os
while 1:
    wd = input("Input full path for directory: ")
    try:
        os.listdir(wd)
    except:
        print("invalid input...")
        continue
    break
list = os.listdir(wd)
print(wd, ": ", end=" ")
try:
    print(os.listdir(wd)) # THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO FORCE THE OUTPUT TO A SINGLE LINE
except:
    print()
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: How will you know how much to "cut the text off at the end" if you don't know how big the window is? The text wrapping is likely being done by the terminal and so even if you decide to cut off a fixed number of characters from the end of your one-line output, resizing the window could result in wrapped output anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For any given width:

```
print_width = 79
```

Just print a slice of a string of the directory contents joined by spaces:

```
print(' '.join(os.listdir(wd))[:print_width])
```

If you don't know the width but can print unicode, you can attempt to replace the spaces with non-breaking spaces, and it may work if your frame doesn't force wrapping:

```
print(u"\u00A0".join(os.listdir(wd)))
```